# Override the reverse router for Play Assets

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am working on a play application and I want to override the [Reverse Asset controller](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Assets). Considering the following code in page.scala.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='@controllers.routes.Assets.at("stylesheet/main.css")'>
```

I'm I would like to override the reverse asset controller to serve from a different host, so that when using the above in templates, the override would do something like this:

```
// read the "staticHost" environment variable, default to empty string
val staticHost = scala.util.Properties.envOrElse("staticHost","")

// if not set, then use the default reverse controller. else use the defined host
if (staticHost.isEmpty)
  super.at(file)
else
  staticHost + file
```

Is this possible at all?

**Solution**

I used a custom method that mimicks the behaviour of the reverse router:

```
def reverseAt(file: String): Call = {
  val prefix = if (basepath.isEmpty) _prefix + { _defaultPrefix } + "assets/" else basepath

  (file: @unchecked) match {
    case (file) if file == "robots.txt" => Call("GET", prefix + "robots.txt")
    case (file) if true => Call("GET", prefix + implicitly[PathBindable[String]].unbind("file", file))

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you won't really be doing any routing to the remote host (i.e., not serving actual responses), there's not really any reason to mess around with the routes controller. You can make a helper object that does the same thing as the reverse assets router, calling the actual reverse assets router when necessary.

```
object Assets {
    val staticHost = scala.util.Properties.envOrElse("staticHost","")

    def at(path: String): String = {
        if (staticHost.isEmpty)
            controllers.routes.Assets.at(file).url
        else
            staticHost + file
    }

}
```

Comment: hi LimbSoup. Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up finding the source for the reverse proxy and then using the same methodology in a custom method